# Is there an inbuilt "Or" function which can be used in a Rust closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I have written the following Rust function, which contains a closure.

```
    fn has_a_none_element(&self) -> bool {

        let elements_is_none =
            self.elements.iter().flatten().map(Option::is_none);

        let optional_any_is_none =
            elements_is_none.reduce(
                |lhs, rhs| {
                    lhs || rhs
                }
            );

        match optional_any_is_none {
            
            None => false,
            Some(any_is_none) => any_is_none,
        }
    }
```

`self.elements` is of type `Vec<Vec<Option<f64>>>`, although this is not particularly important.

What is important is the closure:

```
|lhs, rhs| {
    lhs || rhs
}
```

This is an "Or" function. It is the sort of thing that one might expect there to already be an inbuilt function for which could be used as part of a closure.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: You're probably looking for `Iterator::any` instead of the `map` + `reduce` with the closure. It also has the benefit of short circuiting.

Comment: @interjay Yes, that's a better solution - feel free to add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing the title directly, there is no named function in the standard library to express the `||` operator. Other operators can be named like `And::and` but since logical-or is only available for `bool` and not custom structs, that isn't a thing.

An adjacent behavior though is available through the `|` operator (a.k.a the [`BitOr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitOr.html) trait) and has identical behavior as `||` on `bool`s besides short-circuiting. Using that we can get this:

```
use std::ops::BitOr;

let optional_any_is_none = elements_is_none.reduce(bool::bitor)
```

---

Addressing the end goal though, @interjay is correct that your entire function can be better expressed by using [`.any()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) instead:

```
fn has_a_none_element(&self) -> bool {
    self.elements.iter()
        .flatten()
        .any(Option::is_none)
}
```